# Use parameters in a bash script using curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm creating a script that does a curl request to a predefined site.
Unfortunately the script find the 3 parameters but the curl doesn't work properly.

Where is the problem? Here is my attempt.

```
random="$(cat something.txt)"
echo "ID: ${random} - File: $1 - Var: $2 - Cookie: $3"
url="$(curl -i -L -X POST --cookie 'info=$3' \
  -F 'var=$2' \
  -F 'submit=Send' \
  -F 'file[]=@$1' \
   https://example.com/upload?id=${random})"
```

The second line with `echo` print out the correct values and the same POST request does not give any problem using directly the parameters but the `curl` fails and gives me the following errors:

```
Warning: setting file /my/path/to.file  
Warning: failed!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Where is the problem?

You need to use double quotes.

[Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will analyse your script and look for errors:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
random="$(cat something.txt)"
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.

Line 3:
url="$(curl -i -L -X POST --cookie 'info=$3' \
^-- SC2034: url appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                                   ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

Line 4:
  -F 'var=$2' \
     ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

Line 6:
  -F 'file[]=@$1' \
     ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.

Line 7:
   https://example.com/upload?id=${random})"
                                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

$
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I don't understant how to quote the file parameter
`\"file[]=@$1\"` doesn't work

Comment: @Timmy Why are you escaping the `"`s?

Comment: Because the string start with `url="$...`

Comment: Btw I tried to remove the escaping characters, now it works like a charm, thank you! I have to study more the quote resolution in bash :)

Comment: @Timmy {shrug}. I don't know how to fix that.